# Making VBA code in Excel to show and hide rows more efficient?

Tags: vba, excel

I have one sheet with checkboxes och a lot of other sheets that I want to show and hide rows depending of the checkbox value.

I have started like this

```
If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("chkOne").Value, "o") Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Phone").Range("OneShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Phone").Range("OneShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("chkPhone").Value, "o") Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Phone").Range("SamsungShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Phone").Range("SamsungShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

    If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("chkPhone").Value, "o") Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Phone").Range("GoogleShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Phone").Range("GoogleShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

This works fine but it feels like I repite myself and I'll do this 20 times. Is there a more efficient way? Select Case?

The first row is the checkbox.
The second or fourth line describes which sheets and lines I want to show and hide (I have named my rows).

**Edit:**
Problem with FunThomas solution.

```
With ActiveWorkbook
.Sheets("TES integrationer").Range("HermesShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = (InStr(.Range("chkHermes").Value, "o") > 0)
End With
```

Nothing happens.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TES integrationer").Range("HermesShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = (InStr(.Range("chkHermes").Value, "o") > 0)
End With
```

Invalid or unqualified reference on the last .Range. Changed the last Range to

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TES integrationer").Range("HermesShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = (InStr(ActiveSheet.Range("chkHermes").Value, "o") > 0)
End With
```

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least reduce your code by writing something like

```
with ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets("Phone").Range("OneShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = (InStr(.Range("chkOne").Value, "o") > 0)
    '...
end with
```

Comment: What is "not working"? Please explain what happens, else we cannot help you.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Your `activesheet` is a different sheet than sheet `Phone`? In that case, you have to use `... InStr(Activesheet.Range("chkOne").Value, "o")...'

Comment: Yes, the checkbox and the rows are in different sheet. It looks simular to to what I wrote but it's not working,
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("phone").Range("ShowHideRows").EntireRow.Hidden = (InStr(ActiveSheet.Range("chkOne").Value, "o") > 0)
    End With

Comment: Hmm. Unless there is something wrong with your Names, I cannot think about a reason why this shouldn't work. Your original code did the job? Btw: You don't have a `on error resume next` statement in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can have and array containing the the Button Reference and another with the Rows Reference

```
ButtonRef = Array("chkOne", "chkTwo", "chkPhone", "ButtonRangeOrName")
RowsRef = Array("OneShowHideRows", "SamsungShowHideRows", "GoogleShowHideRows", "RowsNameOrRange")

For n = 0 To ButtonRef
    If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range(ButtonRef(n)).value, "o") Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Phone").Range(RowsRef(n)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Phone").Range(RowsRef(n)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next
```

That way will substantially reduce the amount of code.